# Return blank cell if no value is found

Tags: excel

What is the most effective formula to meet those conditions:

1. If the cell value is greater than 1, than return me 0
2. If the cell value is equal to 1, return me 1
3. If the cell is blank (even though it has some formula inside), return me a blank cell
4. If the cell value is equal to 0, return me a blank cell

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried using `IF` and maybe `OR`?

Comment: I tried to use IF but I could not find a good way to meet all those conditions using only one formula

Comment: @ScottCraner Exactly what I was looking for. You guys are the best!!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OR and nest IF:

```
=IF(OR(A1={"",0}),"",IF(A1=1,1,0))
```

[image]